# change date in infopath form via javascript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, infopath, date, datepicker

I have a sharepoint 2019 site.
in this site i create a list with two column (1.name[text type] 2.Date[DateTime Type]). then i design this list in infopath.
When I want to add a new item, I change the date field value to a new Hijri value (1398/05/27). So far everything is working properly.
The challenge is that when I want to save this item, I have to change it again to Gregorian (2019-08-18). i do this by javascript and change onclick event of Save button.

```
document.getElementById(SaveButton.id).setAttribute("onclick", "$.when(changeDatesBeforeSave()).then(Button.OnClick(this, event));");

function changeDatesBeforeSave() {    
    //my statements for Convert Hijri Date to Gregorian Date .......
    //Gregorian_Date is now set Correctly .....
    //dtcontrolId is input field that keep Date ....

    document.getElementById(dtcontrolId).value = miladiDate;   
}
```

when i click Save button, value in date field changed but it back again to previous value.

```
dtcontrolId // my input date field (it is date picker)
main value : 2019-08-18
first change Gregorian to Hijri : 1398/05/27
user change date to : 1398/02/11
second change Hijri to Gregorian : 2019-05-01
but after press save button value change again to : 2019-08-18
```

why this change back again?
 i hope can explain Problem.

Comment: I re-read your question 3 times and I am still not sure what you are asking. Can you add more details and maybe, rephrase what you are asking in different words, please?

Comment: i explain again . Hope you noticed

Answer (score 0):

Maybe instead of using JavaScript, you can just change the Date picker's format to use Hijra?

I am borrowing the answer from [Wael](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wael/author/wael/).

To do that, follow these steps:

- Add a date picker control…
- Right click the control and click properties…

[image]

- In the display tab, click on format
- Make sure that the locale is the locale is you want. For Arabic or Islamic choose "Arabic (Saudi Arabia)"
- Click on OK few times!

[image]

[image]

Comment: i need Hijri Shamsi (persian Date) and unfortunately sharepoint and infopath don`t support this. also we want save date to Gregorian date format.

Comment: I think date picker stores value temporary somewhere other than input element. i guess have to find and change that ...